# C: Pass socket connection via execl

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, client, server

I am attempting to create a basic server that supports multiple clients.  I want the main server to connect to two clients, and then fork off and pass the file descriptors for the clients to another program via a call to execl.  Both of the clients connect to the server and are able to communicate with it (tested via asking the clients for user names or handles), but when I attempt to pass the clients to the second program (which is meant to be a personal server between the clients to host a board game match) no output is shown on the client's end when the second program attempts to contact them, I am positive it is the way I am attempting to pass the connection information.  Any help with passing the connections correctly is appreciated.

Here is the code for the main server after it accepts two connections:

Main Server: Note. Added additional error checking as recommended.

```
    if(fork() == 0){
        close(listener);
        int nBytes;
        char* playerOne[20];
        char* playerTwo[20];

        //Creates strings to hold file descriptor information for execl
        char connAscii[sizeof(int)];
        char connAscii2[sizeof(int)];
        snprintf(connAscii,sizeof(conn), "%d", conn);
        snprintf(connAscii2,sizeof(conn2), "%d", conn2);
        fprintf(stderr, "Int conn: %d, asciiConn: %s, backToInt: %d", conn, connAscii, atoi(connAscii));
        char *argf[2];
        argf[0] = connAscii; 
        argf[1] = connAscii2;


        //Send Handle Request to Connection 1
        nBytes = send(conn, handleRequest, sizeof(handleRequest),0);
        if(nBytes == -1){
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Receive Handle from Connection 1
        nBytes = recv(conn, playerOne, 20, 0);
        if(nBytes == -1){
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Send Handle Request to Connection 2
        nBytes = send(conn2, handleRequest, sizeof(handleRequest),0);
        if(nBytes == -1){
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Receive Handle from Connection 2
        nBytes = recv(conn2, playerTwo, 20, 0);
        if(nBytes == -1){
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Send Handle for Connection 2 to Connection 1
        nBytes = send(conn, playerTwo, sizeof(playerTwo),0);
        if(nBytes == -1){
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Send Handle for Connection 1 to Connection 2
        nBytes = send(conn2, playerOne, sizeof(playerOne),0);
        if(nBytes == -1){
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }

        //Passes file descriptors to nimMatch
        execl("nimMatch", "nimMatch", argf, (char *)0); 
    }
```

The personal server(different .c file than main server): Note. Added debuging statements

```
char greet[] = {"Hello players, please wait for match setup."};
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int conn1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    int conn2 = atoi(argv[2]);
    int sent;
    fprintf(stderr, "Attempting connection\n");
    sent = send(conn1, greet,sizeof(greet),0);
    if(sent == -1){
        perror("send");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the client code after it has been connected and matched with an opponent:

```
printf("Your opponent is: %s\n\n Connecting to match server...",      otherHandle);
memset(&buf[0],0,sizeof(buf));
if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, 99, 0)) == -1) {  //should come from personal server
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }
printf("From match server: %s\n", buf);
```

If more code is needed let me know,  I know that the clients successfully connect to the server and I get no errors when compiling or running.

The suggested answer from EJP ensures the private server receives the correct input, but the client does not appear to be storing the string from the private server.  The adjusted client code below states that the client is receiving 64 bytes but the buf is empty.

```
 printf("You're opponent is: %s\n\n Connecting to match server...", otherHandle);
memset(&buf[0],0,sizeof(buf));
numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, 99, 0);
if (numbytes == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }
if(strlen(buf) < 1)
    fprintf(stderr, "No buffer input, found %d bytes\n", numbytes);
printf("From match server: %s\n", buf);
```

Comment: You aren't checking the values returned by send() and recv().  Without checking those values, you don't know how many bytes were actually sent or received, and without knowing that, your program cannot work reliably.  In particular you should not think that send() and recv() will return either an error or the number of bytes you passed in; they can (and sometimes will) return a non-negative value that is less that the number of bytes you passed in, indicating a partial send or receive.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thank you I didn't know that, I'm new to network programming and I'll change that in my code.  However I do not believe that is part of this exact problem because the clients don't seem to receive anything from the match server.   But thank you for saving me future headache.

Comment: The match server (3rd code block) seems to be getting hung up on the send command all together.

Comment: You mean the recv() call. There is no send() call in the third code block.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the second code block @EJP

Comment: Then you're mistaken. The second code piece will not block. It will transfer that string to the socket send buffer and return immediately. Are you sure the file descriptors are being passed around correctly? All, and I do mean *all,* the system calls here need error checking. It's pointless to discuss this further until you fix that and report the results. Don't treat error-handling as though it's something you only add after the code works. It's required for debugging, from the beginning.

Comment: @EJP I added some debugging statements around the send in the second code block and it prints the statement before the send but not the one after, that's why I'm thinking it's getting hung on the send.  I will add more error checks to other parts but I know that conn and conn2 in the first block of code (the main server) are correct because the clients can recv information sent to them from the main server via those file descriptors.  I do not know if I am sending them to the second block of code (the private server) correctly.

Comment: Sigh. ***`send()` is a system call.*** You have to check its return value for -1 and call `perror()` just like you do for `socket(), bind(), listen(), accept(), connect(), recv(),` and `close().` Just length-checking it is not enough, and in fact it is pointless in blocking mode as it will never return a short count.

Comment: @EJP I adjusted the error checks. Now I am 99.999999% sure it has something to do with the passing of the file descriptors because when I asked the matched server to print argv[1] I got gibberish instead of the file descriptor.  I believe I am forming argf incorrectly in the main server.

Comment: this line: 'execl("nimMatch", "nimMatch", argf, (char *)0)', per the man page, should be: 'execl("nimMatch", "nimMatch", argf[0],, argv[1], (char *)0)'  as each argument has to be a pointer to string, not a pointer to pointers to strings

Comment: the send() function will hang if both ends of the socket are not open.  I.E. if the receiving end is not open.  And socket is just a small integer number.  to pass it around, it must already be open before performing the fork()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the arguments to `execl()` incorrectly. It doesn't take an argument array, it takes a varargs list of arguments. It should be

```
execl(path, connAscii, connAscii2, (char*)0);
```

Comment: Thank you, now the match server receives the file descriptor correctly, but the clients do not display the feedback from the match server, however the match server does now progress past the send.

Comment: Well it kind of is, in the client code where it says to printf( "From match server %s\n" ,buf) it prints From match server but not the buf

Comment: It should be `printf("From match server %.*s\n, numbytes, buf);` You don't need the `memset()`, and the `strlen()` test is invalid: remove it.

Comment: Ok I made those changes and it's still not showing anything from buf.  I'm getting: You're opponent is: kk

 Connecting to match server...From match server:

Comment: Change it to `printf("From match server %.*s (%d bytes)\n, numbytes, buf, numbytes)` to see how many bytes were received. And what are `handleRequest`, `playerOne`, `playerTwo` exactly?

Comment: It says that it received 61 bytes but doesn't print them.  handleRequest is a message (char []) sent to the clients asking for their user name and playerOne and playerTwo are both char[20] that store the user names for both clients @EJP

Comment: when I attempt to print the buf char by char I get gibberish, is the issue with how I am sending it? The send in the second block of code appears correct.

Comment: Because this is a different issue and you fixed my original question I accepted your answer and posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308845/recv-buffer-empty-but-returns-a-value-1