# RECV buffer empty, but returns a value > 1

Tags: c, client-server, server, send, recv

I am attempting to make a simple server so that two clients can communicate with each other.  The main server code accepts the two client connections and then forks off a process that uses execl to generate a personal server between the two clients so that the main server can continue looking for new connections.  Everything seems to work correctly until the personal server attempts to contact the clients and they both receive gibberish, if anyone knows what could cause this please let me know.

Main server after accepting two clients:

```
if(fork() == 0){
        close(listener);
        int nBytes;
        char* playerOne[20];
        char* playerTwo[20];

        //Creates strings to hold file descriptor information for execl
        char connAscii[sizeof(int)];
        char connAscii2[sizeof(int)];
        snprintf(connAscii,sizeof(conn), "%d", conn);
        snprintf(connAscii2,sizeof(conn2), "%d", conn2);
        fprintf(stderr, "Int conn: %d, asciiConn: %s, backToInt: %d\n", conn, connAscii, atoi(connAscii));
        char *argf[2];
        argf[0] = connAscii; 
        argf[1] = connAscii2;
        fprintf(stderr, "that is to say %s and %s\n", argf[0], argf[1]);

        //Send Handle Request to Connection 1
        nBytes = send(conn, handleRequest, sizeof(handleRequest),0);
        if(nBytes == -1){
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Receive Handle from Connection 1
        nBytes = recv(conn, playerOne, 20, 0);
        if(nBytes == -1){
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Send Handle Request to Connection 2
        nBytes = send(conn2, handleRequest, sizeof(handleRequest),0);
        if(nBytes == -1){
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Receive Handle from Connection 2
        nBytes = recv(conn2, playerTwo, 20, 0);
        if(nBytes == -1){
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Send Handle for Connection 2 to Connection 1
        nBytes = send(conn, playerTwo, sizeof(playerTwo),0);
        if(nBytes == -1){
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Send Handle for Connection 1 to Connection 2
        nBytes = send(conn2, playerOne, sizeof(playerOne),0);
        if(nBytes == -1){
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }

        //Passes file descriptors to privateServer
        execl("privateServer","privateServer", connAscii, connAscii2, (char *)0); 
}
```

Personal server invoked by execl:

```
char greet[] = {"Hello players, please wait for match setup."};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int conn1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    int conn2 = atoi(argv[2]);
    int sent;
    fprintf(stderr, "Attempting connection with %d\n", conn1);
    sent = send(conn1, greet,sizeof(greet),0);
    if(sent == -1){
        perror("send");
        exit(1);
    }

    sent = send(conn2, greet,sizeof(greet),0);
    if(sent == -1){
        perror("send");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(stderr,"Hopefully they got it\n");
    return 0;
    }
```

Clients: Reading the recv buff char by char results in gibberish and printing the entire buffer doesn't show anything, but numbytes == 61.

```
char *buff = (char*)malloc(100);
memset(&buff[0],0,sizeof(buff));
numbytes = recv(sockfd, buff, 99, 0);  //should be from private server
if (numbytes == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }
buff[numbytes] = '\0';
int i;
for(i = 0; i < numbytes; i++){
    fprintf(stderr, "%c", buff[i]);
}
printf("From match server: %.*s (%d bytes)\n", numbytes, buff, numbytes);
```

Comment: `char* playerOne[20];` --> `char playerOne[20];`, same for `playerTwo`

Comment: Thank you I'll fix that, but playerOne and playerTwo have no issue being sent from the main server to the clients while I am unable to send the message from the private server to the clients @AlterMann

Comment: Actually that fixed the entire issue.  What a wonderful world this is that hours of work are resolved by removing a *

Comment: You have another problem, see my answer

Comment: regarding this kind of line: 'char* playerOne[20];'  This is declaring an array of 20 pointers to characters.  Probably not what is wanted.  suggest: 'char playerOne[20];' so it is declaring an array of characters rather than an array of pointers to characters

Comment: regarding the call to malloc()  1) in C, the returned value should not be cast  2) the returned value should always be checked (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: there are several 'magic' numbers in the code, for instance 100 and 99.  magic numbers, for readability and clarity, should be #define'd with meaningful names.  With out the #define, it is a guess as to what the number signify.   Another good result of #define is that updates/maintenance only needs to update the number in the #define statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors:

```
char* playerOne[20];
char* playerTwo[20];
```

You want an array of chars, not an array of pointers to chars

change to

```
char playerOne[20];
char playerTwo[20];
```

And here:

```
char *buff = (char*)malloc(100);
memset(&buff[0],0,sizeof(buff));
```

`sizeof(buff)` is the size of a pointer to `char`, change to

```
memset(&buff[0],0,100);
```

As pointed out by @user3629249, don't use magic numbers like 100, instead

```
#define MAX_BUFF 100
char *buff = malloc(MAX_BUFF);
memset(&buff[0],0,MAX_BUFF);
```

But there is no need to `memset` if you are null-terminating the string.

Comment: that '100' would be an excellent place to have a #define'd value,  then debug, maintenance, and clarity would be greatly improved.  Please remember that others need to understand your code.  Even you, after some interval of time has passed will benefit from a meaningfully named #define for the value '100'

Comment: The memset is cargo-cult rubbish anyway.  It's totally pointless if you are going to assemble a null-terminated string in the next couple lines.

Comment: The null-termination at the read count is also cargo-cult programming. You should pass around the read count returnd by `recv().` You can't assume that data received is text and should be null-terminated, and it wastes an element in your receive buffer. If you forget the -1 it causes a bug.

Comment: @EJP oops you're right,  for some reason I was thinking that those variables were passed to `execl` as a parameter.